# Can't I change a string containing "+" to another string in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark

I wanna change "75+ years" to "old age" in age column.

```
columns = ["age", "any"]
data = [("middle age", "male"), ("75+ years", "female"), ("10-20 years", "male")]
dfFromData = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)
test.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZxS9.png)

```
test.withColumn("age", regexp_replace("age", "75+ years", "old age")).show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feJKo.png)

I could change a string containing "-" at will. ("10-20 years")
But a string containing "+" can't change using same method. ("75+ years")

What is the difference between does two?

Answer (score 1):

Try using replace() function instead of withColumn() + regexp_replace:

```
dfFromData.replace("75+ years", "old age").show()
```

This will replace all the "75+ years" value in your dataframe by "old age".

```
+-----------+------+
|        age|   any|
+-----------+------+
| middle age|  male|
|    old age|female|
|10-20 years|  male|
+-----------+------+
```

Add a subset if you want to apply the replace on a specific column:

```
dfFromData.replace("75+ years", "old age", subset='age').show()
```

By the way, there is a little typo in your code, you defined a dfFromData then you manipulate another object called test.

Hope it helps!

EDIT: To answer your specific question about why regexp doesn't work with '+' symbol. It's because '+' is a special character for python regexp (see doc for more details). If you want to use regexp with `'+'`, just replace it by `'\+'` as follow:

```
dfFromData.withColumn("age", regexp_replace("age", "75\+ years", "old age")).show()
```

It will give you the desired result.